# What is the scope of the [utility] tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

It was pointed out to me that the description of the [utility](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/utility) is ambiguous. It currently reads:

> A tag for all questions involving a type of utility function.

With a wiki which is even worse:

> STUB!!! See [utility function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility).

Since I figured that I don't have enough knowledge about this topic, I wanted to poll someone else's opinion and expertise to help and clarify this tag's proper usage (or necessity, in case usage is too ambiguous).

Comment: To people who know what a utility function is, the tag description looks fine. However, I've to agree the tag wiki is  way too terse...

Comment: @achillehui: The problem is that some people *don't* know what a utility function is, and the excerpt should provide a quick guideline. For example, that these questions are often tagged under something like finance, or economics, or so on. And *not* under functional analysis, or whatever.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Results related to utility theory might occur in functional analysis, measure theory, and even -gasp- [set theory](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304406876900240).

Comment: @Michael: Sure. I was just tossing tags for sake of example...

Comment: @Michael: Not to mention, the Wikipedia links literally opens with "*In economics, **utility** is a measure of preferences over some set of goods*"...

Comment: (Admittedly, I'm not sure what the downvote signifies in this case. Is it against having a discussion on tags? Is it against having a discussion on *this* tag? Is it something else? Please, enlighten me!)

Comment: "What is the utility of [utility]?" :-)

Comment: @quid: Ah, crap. I can't believe I missed that one!!!

Comment: Surely, the usage of every other "utility" other than the function itself is off-topic here, but can we have it renamed as [utility-function] for clarity?

Answer (score 16):

I have edited the description and the tag-wiki. They are now:

> For all questions involving utility function as used in economics and
>   decision theory, including a study of their properties or how they can
>   be used to represent preferences.

and

> A [utility function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Utility) is a numerical representation of an agents
>   preferences. If $\succeq$ is a preference relation on a set of
>   alternatives $X$, then the function $u: X\to\mathbb{R}$ is a *utility
>   representation* of $\succeq$ if $x\succeq y$ holds if and only if
>   $u(x)\ge u(y)$. In many cases, one might want the representation to be
>   of a special form. For example, if $X$ is the set of probability
>   distributions on a finite set $F=\{y_1,\ldots,y_n\}$ so that
>   $x=(p_1,\ldots,p_n)$, then an *expected utility representation* of
>   $\succeq$ is of the form  $$u(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n p_iv(y_i)$$ for some
>   function $v:F\to\mathbb{R}$.

respectively.